# Increase frequency of labels on each contour - matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

Is there an easy way to increase the frequency of contour labels within clabel() or do I need to manually position all of my labels?

[image: Full map of contours with few lables]

Even when I zoom in the labels still don't show on all of them.

[image: US map of contours with few labels]

Is there any easy argument for clabel? I'd ultimately like all contours labeled and maybe two or three labels per contour through out the image.

Can post code if needed, thanks

Comment: *"Is there any easy argument for clabel?"* - The answer is no. See [clabel documentation](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.clabel.html).